# XSLT 1.0 grouping by multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I came through various answers regarding this topic but I couldn't find a solution so far.

I have input XML with the structure like this:

```
<RootNode>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM11</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM22</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM23</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM24</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABD</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD21</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD22</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD23</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD24</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM32</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM33</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM34</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>002</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD31</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD32</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD33</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD34</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM42</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM43</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM44</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM51</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM52</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM53</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM54</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
</RootNode>
```

The result of the transformation should look like this:

```
<ResultXml>
  <record>
    <header>
      <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
      <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
      <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
      <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
      <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
      <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
      <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
    </header>
    <item>
      <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM11</ITEMELEMENT1>
      <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT2>
      <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT3>
      <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT4>       
    </item>     
    <item>
      <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT1>
      <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM22</ITEMELEMENT2>
      <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM23</ITEMELEMENT3>
      <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM24</ITEMELEMENT4>       
    </item>     
    <item>
      <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM51</ITEMELEMENT1>
      <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM52</ITEMELEMENT2>
      <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM53</ITEMELEMENT3>
      <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM54</ITEMELEMENT4>       
    </item>
  </record>
  <record>
    <header>
      <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
      <KEYELEMENT2>ABD</KEYELEMENT2>
      <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
      <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD21</HEADELEMENT1>
      <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD22</HEADELEMENT2>
      <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD23</HEADELEMENT3>
      <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD24</HEADELEMENT4>
    </header>
    <item>
      <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT1>
      <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM32</ITEMELEMENT2>
      <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM33</ITEMELEMENT3>
      <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM34</ITEMELEMENT4>       
    </item>
  </record>
  <record>
    <header>
      <KEYELEMENT1>002</KEYELEMENT1>
      <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
      <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
      <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD31</HEADELEMENT1>
      <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD32</HEADELEMENT2>
      <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD33</HEADELEMENT3>
      <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD34</HEADELEMENT4>
    </header>
    <item>
      <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT1>
      <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM42</ITEMELEMENT2>
      <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM43</ITEMELEMENT3>
      <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM44</ITEMELEMENT4>       
    </item>
  </record>   
</ResultXml>
```

For each distinct values in KEYELEMENT1, KEYELEMENT2, and KEYELEMENT3 I have to create one record in the result. Other header fields are the same and are transformed to header element with the key fields. Items should be mapped under the record with the same keys.

I tried the Muenchian method with something like this:

```
    <xsl:key name="keyfields" match="record" use="concat(KEYELEMENT1, '|', KEYELEMENT2, '|', KEYELEMENT3)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ResultXml>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyfields',concat(KEYELEMENT1, '|', KEYELEMENT2, '|', KEYELEMENT3))[1])]" mode="header"/>
    </ResultXml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record" mode="header">
    <record>
        <header>
            <KEYELEMENT1><xsl:value-of select="KEYELEMENT1"/></KEYELEMENT1>
            <KEYELEMENT2><xsl:value-of select="KEYELEMENT2"/></KEYELEMENT2>
            <KEYELEMENT3><xsl:value-of select="KEYELEMENT3"/></KEYELEMENT3>
            <HEADELEMENT1><xsl:value-of select="HEADELEMENT1"/></HEADELEMENT1>
            <HEADELEMENT2><xsl:value-of select="HEADELEMENT2"/></HEADELEMENT2>
            <HEADELEMENT3><xsl:value-of select="HEADELEMENT3"/></HEADELEMENT3>
            <HEADELEMENT4><xsl:value-of select="HEADELEMENT4"/></HEADELEMENT4>          
        </header>
    </record>       
</xsl:template>
```

But I am not able to produce even header records.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Muenchiann grouping* in **XSLT 1.0** requires a bit of ordered approach
and careful usage of a number of *grouping idioms*.

We must start from creation of a **key**, to group records, in this case on
KEYELEMENT1 / ...2 / ...3.

Then the main template (matching *RootNode*) applies "group" template
to the first record from each group.

The "group" template for `record`:

- prints opening `record` tag,
- prints `head` element filled with *KEY...* and *HEAD...*
  source elements,
- calls "normal" template to all members of the current group,
- and finally, prints closing `record` tag.

The "normal" template for `record` prints `item` element filled
with *ITEM...* source elements.

And the last thing you need is the *identity template*.

So the whole script looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="recs" match="record"
    use="concat(KEYELEMENT1, '|', KEYELEMENT2, '|', KEYELEMENT3)"/>

  <xsl:template match="RootNode">
    <ResultXml>
      <!-- Apply "group" template to the first record in group -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="record[generate-id() = generate-id(
        key('recs', concat(KEYELEMENT1, '|', KEYELEMENT2, '|', KEYELEMENT3))
        [1])]" mode="group"/>
    </ResultXml>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- "Group" template for record -->
  <xsl:template match="record" mode="group">
    <record>
      <head>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(), 'KEY') or starts-with(name(), 'HEAD')]"/>
      </head>
      <!-- Apply "normal" template to all members of the current group -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('recs',
        concat(KEYELEMENT1, '|', KEYELEMENT2, '|', KEYELEMENT3))"/>
    </record>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- "Normal" template for record -->
  <xsl:template match="record">
    <item>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(), 'ITEM')]"/>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2k

Comment: I think your logic of each `item` is just based on the `record` instead of my logic that they're grouped in bunches of 4 is probably more likely. +1 However, why include the identity template if you're just going to use `xsl:copy-of`?

Comment: *Daniel* is right about the *identity template*. As all the content is copied using *copy-of*, this template is just not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your first template match from `/` to `/*` (or `RootNode`) you'll get your groups correctly.

After that it's just a matter of grouping the items into sets of 4. One way to do that is by using `mod` in a predicate.

Here's an example. I use `count()` instead of `generate-id()` in my Muenchian grouping, but it can be done either way.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<RootNode>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM11</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM22</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM23</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM24</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABD</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD21</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD22</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD23</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD24</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM32</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM33</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM34</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>002</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD31</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD32</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD33</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD34</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM42</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM43</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM44</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
    <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
    <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
    <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
    <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
    <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
    <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM51</ITEMELEMENT1>
    <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM52</ITEMELEMENT2>
    <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM53</ITEMELEMENT3>
    <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM54</ITEMELEMENT4>
  </record>
</RootNode>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="keyfields" match="record"
    use="concat(KEYELEMENT1,'|',KEYELEMENT2,'|',KEYELEMENT3)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <ResultXml>
      <xsl:for-each
        select="record[count(.|key('keyfields',concat(KEYELEMENT1,'|',KEYELEMENT2,'|',KEYELEMENT3))[1])=1]">
        <record>
          <header>
            <xsl:apply-templates
              select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'KEYELEMENT') or starts-with(local-name(), 'HEADELEMENT')]"/>
          </header>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('keyfields',concat(KEYELEMENT1,'|',KEYELEMENT2,'|',KEYELEMENT3))/*[starts-with(local-name(),'ITEMELEMENT')][position() mod 4 = 1]">
            <item>
              <xsl:apply-templates 
                select=".|following-sibling::*[starts-with(local-name(),'ITEMELEMENT')][position() >= 1 and 4 > position()]"/>
            </item>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ResultXml>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<ResultXml>
   <record>
      <header>
         <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
         <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
         <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
         <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD11</HEADELEMENT1>
         <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD12</HEADELEMENT2>
         <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD13</HEADELEMENT3>
         <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD14</HEADELEMENT4>
      </header>
      <item>
         <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM11</ITEMELEMENT1>
         <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT2>
         <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT3>
         <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT4>
      </item>
      <item>
         <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM21</ITEMELEMENT1>
         <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM22</ITEMELEMENT2>
         <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM23</ITEMELEMENT3>
         <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM24</ITEMELEMENT4>
      </item>
      <item>
         <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM51</ITEMELEMENT1>
         <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM52</ITEMELEMENT2>
         <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM53</ITEMELEMENT3>
         <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM54</ITEMELEMENT4>
      </item>
   </record>
   <record>
      <header>
         <KEYELEMENT1>001</KEYELEMENT1>
         <KEYELEMENT2>ABD</KEYELEMENT2>
         <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
         <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD21</HEADELEMENT1>
         <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD22</HEADELEMENT2>
         <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD23</HEADELEMENT3>
         <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD24</HEADELEMENT4>
      </header>
      <item>
         <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM31</ITEMELEMENT1>
         <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM32</ITEMELEMENT2>
         <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM33</ITEMELEMENT3>
         <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM34</ITEMELEMENT4>
      </item>
   </record>
   <record>
      <header>
         <KEYELEMENT1>002</KEYELEMENT1>
         <KEYELEMENT2>ABC</KEYELEMENT2>
         <KEYELEMENT3>EFG</KEYELEMENT3>
         <HEADELEMENT1>HEAD31</HEADELEMENT1>
         <HEADELEMENT2>HEAD32</HEADELEMENT2>
         <HEADELEMENT3>HEAD33</HEADELEMENT3>
         <HEADELEMENT4>HEAD34</HEADELEMENT4>
      </header>
      <item>
         <ITEMELEMENT1>ITEM41</ITEMELEMENT1>
         <ITEMELEMENT2>ITEM42</ITEMELEMENT2>
         <ITEMELEMENT3>ITEM43</ITEMELEMENT3>
         <ITEMELEMENT4>ITEM44</ITEMELEMENT4>
      </item>
   </record>
</ResultXml>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yi